# Create modal dynamically from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am dumping a html code of a div in json format at client side.I am using Django Channels Groups to do this.

**Server-Side**

```
def my_view(obj1,obj2):
    #---------------------some_existing_lines_of_code-----------------------------------#

    notification={"id":"<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"lab-slide-bottom-popup\" data-keyboard=\"false\" data-backdrop=\"false\"><div class=\"lab-modal-body\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span></button><form>Name: <input id=\"v_name\" type=\"text\" name=\"visitor_name\" ><br><br>E-mail: <input id=\"v_email\" type=\"email\" name=\"emailaddress\"><br><br>Inquiry:<select id=\"v_inquiry\"><option value=\"Sales\">Sales</option><option value=\"Support\">Support</option><option value=\"Contact\">Contact</option></select><br><br><input class=\"submit-btn\" type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\"></form></div></div>"}

    Group(group_name).send({"text": json.dumps(notification),})
```

Now at client side i am listening this data sent by server

**Client-Side**

```
webSocketBridge.listen(function(text)
 {
    //Here i have to use the data sent by server to create the modal.I need your help here.What i think it should be something like following

        $("body").html(text.id);

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {
          setTimeout(function() {
           $('#lab-slide-bottom-popup').modal('show'); }, 2000);
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.lab-slide-up').find('a').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
           $('.lab-slide-up').find('a').attr('data-target', '#lab-slide-bottom-popup');
         }); });
});
```

When my code runs rather than showing up the modal, a blank page is shown to me.How do i use the JSON sent by my server to create modal dynamically?

I have provided the source of script jquery,link to stylesheet of this modal and other necessary scripts at client side but i haven't shown them here just to maintain clarity otherwise it would have looked messy.'

**P.S: Everything is working perfectly fine at server end.Server is sending JSON formatted data at client side and i have verified it by using the following function in browser's console.**

```
console.log("This is data sent by server----",JSON.stringify(text.id)));
```

and i got to see the following result in the console:

```
This is data sent by server---- "<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"lab-slide-bottom-popup\" data-keyboard=\"false\" data-backdrop=\"false\"><div class=\"lab-modal-body\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span></button><form>Name: <input id=\"v_name\" type=\"text\" name=\"visitor_name\" ><br><br>E-mail: <input id=\"v_email\" type=\"email\" name=\"emailaddress\"><br><br>Inquiry:<select id=\"v_inquiry\"><option value=\"Sales\">Sales</option><option value=\"Support\">Support</option><option value=\"Contact\">Contact</option></select><br><br><!--<input class=\"btn-primary btn-plain btn btn-lg popup-button\" style=\"margin-top:-5px;\" type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\">--><input class=\"submit-btn\" type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\"></form></div></div>"
```

I have got one error too which is as follows;

```
sp.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function at sp.js:63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that you're using `$('body').html` which is going to replace the entire set of content with the modal. The other part is that I think you need to use `jQuery.parseHTML()`. So here's what I'd recommend:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    webSocketBridge.listen(function(text) {
        $("body").append($.parseHTML(text.id);
        $('#lab-slide-bottom-popup').modal('show');
        $('.lab-slide-up').find('a').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $('.lab-slide-up').find('a').attr('data-target', '#lab-slide-bottom-popup');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sir @schillingt, `sp.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function` i am getting this error now

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct JS libraries imported? Looks like you're missing whatever library defines modal.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Yes you were right. Library was not imported properly. Now i have rectified it.Thanks a ton.